# Deploy script for Meteor.com hosting via Codeship

Tags: meteor, continuous-deployment

I'm using Meteor's built-in hosting for staging, with Codeship handling the continuous deployment. All tests and notifications succeed as expected in Codeship, but nothing is getting deployed.

My script:

```
expect -c "set timeout 60; spawn meteor deploy staging.myapp.com; expect “Email:” { send $METEOR_DEPLOY_EMAIL\r; expect eof } expect "Password:" { send $METEOR_DEPLOY_PASSWORD\r; expect eof }"
```

When that script runs during the build process I see the following:

```
spawn meteor deploy staging.myapp.com
=> Running Meteor from a checkout -- overrides project version (0.8.1)
To instantly deploy your app on a free testing server, just enter your
email address!
ail:
```

The `ail:` isn't a typo...that's what Codeship displays. It appears it eventually times out and moves on, though no errors are shown.

First time setting up a CI server (and using Expect), so thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out...had two syntax issues:

1. Left/right double quotation marks snuck in there (instead of
   standard quotation mark)
2. Missing semicolon

So, for anyone looking for a script to deploy to *.meteor.com using Codeship, here is the working script:

```
expect -c "set timeout 60; spawn meteor deploy example.com; expect "Email:" { send $METEOR_DEPLOY_EMAIL\r; expect eof }; expect "Password:" { send $METEOR_DEPLOY_PASSWORD\r; expect eof }"
```

Comment: When I run it as is (with the two variables in place) I get the following error :  `missing close-brace
while executing
"expect Password: {"
couldn't read file "0|sh\r; expect eof };": no such file or directory`any idea?

Comment: Make sure the syntax is exact. E.g. `expect "Password:` should be `expect "Password:"` (note the missing double quote in your string. Looks like you might also have an extra semicolon at the end. Good luck!